# Inferring arbitrary function arguments as object or tuple type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, arguments, type-inference

I'm looking for something like this type:

```
type ArgsType<F extends Function> = ...
```

where

```
ArgsType<(n: number, s: string)=>void>
```

will give me

```
[number, string]
```

or

```
{n: number, s: string}
```

Based on one of the answers, I created these types:

```
type ArgsType<F extends (...x: any[]) => any>
    = F extends (...x: infer A) => any ? A : never;

type CtorArgsType<F extends new (...x: any[]) => any>
    = F extends new (...x: infer A) => any ? A : never;


interface RepoGroup {
    resetAsync?: () => Promise<void>
}

interface RepoGroupOptions<Reset extends "CanReset" | "CannotReset"="CannotReset"> {
    reset: Reset extends "CanReset" ? () => Promise<void> : undefined
}

type RepoGroupCtor<Reset extends "CanReset" | "CannotReset"="CannotReset">
    = new (...args: any[]) => RepoGroupOptions<Reset>


export function generate<
    CanReset extends "CanReset" | "CannotReset"="CannotReset",
    T extends RepoGroupCtor<CanReset>=RepoGroupCtor<CanReset>
    >(args: T) {
    return class implements RepoGroup {
        private args: InstanceType<T>
        constructor(...config: CtorArgsType<T>) {
            this.args = new args(config) as any
        }

        resetAsync = this.args.reset
    }
}


export const Repo = generate(class {
    readonly baseUrl: string
    constructor(args: { apiBaseUrl: string }) {
        this.baseUrl = args.apiBaseUrl
    }

    reset: undefined
})

let repository = new Repo()
```

The last line shows an error, as it should. But if I add just a generic parameter to the *repo* thus:

```
export const Repo = generate<"CannotReset">(class {...
```

then the error disappears, which seems like a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

which is [proposed to be added to the standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26243/files#diff-a6b488d9bd802977827b535a3011c1f3R1384).

### Round 2

When you pass at least one type argument to `generate`, you shut off inference for the remaining type arguments and the defaults are used (`T = RepoGroupCtor<CanReset>`), and `RepoGroupCtor<CanReset>` accepts a rest parameter of `any[]`, hence there is no error.  [Partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) would give you a way to avoid this.

Comment: Ok, this worked for me, but applying it to a constructor function that return a generic object, it no longer works properly

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: as of Typescript 3.2.2, `Parameters<T>` is merged and it works like a charm (`Parameters<typeof myFunction>` or `Parameters<functionType>`).  Its probably working since 3.1, but i cannot gurantee that. See: `sandersn merged 1 commit into master from add-parameter-to-tuple-type on 31 Aug 2018`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Parameters<T>`. It is available since (at least) 3.2

Usage:

```js
function log(s: string) { console.log(s)}
type LogArg = Parameters<typeof log>[0]; // string

interface Logger {
 log(s: string) => void;
}
type LogArg2 = Parameters<Logger['log']>[0]; // string
```